# Create new list (or numpy.array) with a named list (or numpy.array)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a name list, and I want to construct a new list of the same type of data inside the list. How can I do it? What if it is a numpy array?

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
newx=[x,5,6]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], 5, 6]

#numpy
y=np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
newy=[y,5,6]
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), 5, 6]
```

Desired output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mere Python lists you do:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x += [5, 6]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and for numpy-arrays:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
x = np.concatenate((x, np.array([5, 6])))
>>> np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Mind the double parentheses in np.concatenate, since the arguments must be passed as a tuple.

Comment: For the python list, what if I still want to keep the variable x and create a new x based on x?

Comment: you can use extend  x = [1,2,3,4]
    y = [5,6]
    x.extend(y)